# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - Array is defined, why am I getting this error?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have an array called `data` which is populated with some values. However, when I try to use the `map` function on it, I get a `TypeError` saying "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". I'm confused because I can clearly see that the array is defined and has elements in it. Here's my code:

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const result = data.map(item => item * 2);
console.log(result);
```

I expected the `map` function to iterate over each element of the `data` array and multiply it by 2, but instead, I'm getting this error. What could be causing this issue? Am I missing something obvious here?

Note: I've double-checked the variable name and made sure there are no typos. The error still persists. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I Copied your code and run it into the browser console window and it is working perfectly fine.

The “TypeError: Cannot Read Property ‘Map’ of Undefined” error typically occurs when you try to access a property or method of an undefined value in your code.

[image]

Comment: This should be comment and not an answer